# mongo db - can't initiate Mongo with replica set

Tags: configuration, mongodb, spring-data

I'm using version spring-data-mongo version 1.0.0.M4 - the latest version to this date.

I defined my bean like this:

```
<bean id="mongoOps" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="my_mongo" />
</bean>

<mongo:mongo id="mongo" replica-set="host1:27017,host2:27018,host3:27019" >
    <mongo:options... />
</mongo:mongo>
```

But when I start my server it try's to connect to the default host and port on my computer, this happens because in MongoFactoryBean line 93 it says:

```
if (host == null) {
    logger.debug("Property host not specified. Using default configuration");
    mongo = new Mongo();
} else {...
    //do all the stuff I want to be done...
}
```

So how can I define my Mongo with a replica-set without setting the host?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the bean declaration be like this - possibly you're missing the ID of the replicaset bean?

`<mongo:mongo id="replicaSetMongo" replica-set="host1:27017,host2:27018"/>`

Comment: It is - the problem is that in this way the host remains null, and the replica set configuration in the factory bean happens in the branch where host is *not* null. (I work with binya)